# Celery import error

Tags: python, django, celery

I am hitting an import error in starting celery.  This is confusing, because this was working a few days ago, and git shows nothing changed.  I think celery's heuristics for import directories are colliding with my split-out setting structure, and maybe my path/env is different than it was when the invokation was working?  How should I tweak my invokation or environment to help celery load all of its downstream imports?  This is Celery 3.1.7 and Django 1.6.

My invokation:

```
celery worker --app=proj.proj
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.7', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 80, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 723, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 303, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 715, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 669, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 175, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 266, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 208, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 128, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 121, in import_default_modules
    tuple(maybe_list(self.app.conf.CELERY_INCLUDE))
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 103, in import_task_module
    return self.import_from_cwd(module)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 112, in import_from_cwd
    package=package,
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 106, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ben/Projects/proj/proj/proj/matches/management/tasks/valve_api_calls.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matches.models import Match, LobbyType, GameMode,\
  File "/home/ben/Projects/proj/proj/proj/matches/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'proj.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.local
```

My project looks like:

```
proj <git root>
└──proj <project root>
   └── manage.py
   └── proj <project app>
       └── celery_app.py
       └── settings
           └── local.py
```

My env vars are:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.settings.local
DJANGO_PROJECT_DIR=/home/ben/Projects/proj/proj/proj
```

EDIT: I am using virtualenv, so my $PATH on startup looks like

```
PATH=/home/ben/.virtualenvs/proj/bin:
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Why do you run `celery` pointing to an app? Moreover, see that you have no package called `proj.proj`

Comment: Celery does some app autodiscovery, but can need help depending on directory structure and filename.  In this case, a default "celery worker" call misses my app (and its configuration).  Specifying proj.proj lets celery find the app, but the stacktrace shows that the chain of imports in the tasks loses context for autodiscovering those modules.

Comment: Can't you use just `tasks.py` for each app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My virtualenv got corrupted somehow.  A new virtualenv with identical env vars and installed software works.

Answer (score 0):

You celery's using the wrong working directory, so it cannot find relative path `proj.settings.local`

Try modifying your setting to `DJANGO_PROJECT_DIR=/home/ben/Projects/proj/proj` and see if it works.

Comment: Trying various levels of /proj/ yields the same error or a discovery issue (insufficiently deep spec misses the app).